# Create key in registry

Tags: c#, wpf, registry

I am developing a WPF application. I want to create a key in the registry in the below path
with key, value (`myapp.exe`, `2710`).

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.

Can any one suggest how to do this from the installer class, `OnBeforeInstall` method.

Regards

Comment: i have to create a 32bit DWORD

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for create a key and put value.

```
 private string _subKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    private string SubKey
    {
        get { return _subKey; }
        set { _subKey = value; }
    }

    private RegistryKey _baseRegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

    private RegistryKey BaseRegistryKey
    {
        get { return _baseRegistryKey; }
        set { _baseRegistryKey = value; }
    }

   private bool WriteDbToRegistry(string keyName, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            var rk = BaseRegistryKey;
            var sk1 = rk.CreateSubKey(SubKey);
            if(sk1 != null) sk1.SetValue(keyName.ToUpper(), value);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please run your App as Administrator.", "Administrator");
            return false;
        }
    }

 bool results = WriteDbToRegistry("myapp.exe", "2710");
```

hope this may be helpful.

Comment: i could not create key

Comment: it is compiling and no errors...but i the entry is not created. i was also suggested  Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true).SetValue("Browsercontrol.exe",2711,RegistryValueKind.DWord);   i was askd to insert this code in the onbeforeinstall method.But it too doest work

Answer (score 0):

Install the **Microsoft.Win32.Registry** NuGet package, and usse it like this:

```cs
    var keyName = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    Registry.SetValue(keyName , "myapp.exe", 2710, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Setting the value adds it if it's missing.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=net-5.0).